# Question about the definition of the net based on a filter

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a filter on a set $X$. The net based on $\mathcal{F}$ is defined as follows:

Consider the set $D =\{(x,F)|x\in F\in \mathcal{F} \}$ ordered by $(x,F)\leq (x',F')$ iff $F'\subseteq F$. Then the net is defined as the map $p(x,F) = x$.

My question is on the construction on the set $D$. If we have fixed some $F\in \mathcal{F}$, then do we only add one element $(x,F)$ where $x$ is some $x\in F$ or do we add ALL the elements $(x,F)$ for all $x\in F?$

Comment: I think, it runs to all $x\in F$.

Comment: Yes, *all* pairs $(x,F)$ where $F\in\mathcal{F}$ and $x\in F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a net on $X$ you need

1. a (pre)ordered set $D,\le$ with the property that, for every $d_1,d_2\in D$, there exists $d\in D$ with $d_1\le d$ and $d_2\le d$;
2. a map $p\colon D\to X$.

Given a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, you want to define a net $(D,p)$ in such a way that, if $\mathcal{F}$ is the filter of neighborhoods of $z\in X$, then the net converges to $z$.

One way could be to *choose*, for every $F\in\mathcal{F}$, an element $x\in F$ (a filter consists of nonempty sets) and define $D$ to be the set of the pairs $(x,F)$ so determined.

On the other hand, this can be done more simply by considering the set of all pairs $(x,F)$ where $F\in\mathcal{F}$ and $x\in F$. No choice needed.

If, in both cases, the map selects the first member of the pair, then the former net is a subnet of the latter.